# How can I get object type for callback depending on enum?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, enums

Imagine you have following TS code:

```
enum stores {
  book,
  chapter,
  verse
}

const reducer = {
  [stores.book]: { a: 'string', b: 1 },
  [stores.chapter]: { a: 'string', c: 2 },
  [stores.verse]: { a: 'string', d: false }
}

function main ({
  storeName,
  getA
}:{
  storeName: stores,
  getA: (item: typeof reducer[stores]) => void
}) {
  const item = reducer[storeName]
  getA(item)
  return
}

main({storeName: stores.verse, getA(item) {
  item.a // only can get common a attribute, but
  item.d // can't get special for stores.verse attribute
}})
```

What should I do to make typescript dynamically understand type of item in getA depending on storeName and reducer?

Working on my React-Redux app rn. I want to make generic component for multiple Redux slices. The API inside component consists only of common attributes, so it's fine and working, but I need to get exact type of object in slice in one of props functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler needs to keep track of the specific member of `stores` which was used to call the function. This can be achieved by declaring a generic type parameter `S` and using it to type `storeName`.

The type of the value passed as `storeName` will be used to infer the type of `S`. The parameter `item` can be typed as `typeof reducers[S]`.

```
function main<S extends stores>({
  storeName,
  getA,
}: {
  storeName: S;
  getA: (item: typeof reducer[S]) => void;
}) {
  const item = reducer[storeName];
  getA(item);
  return;
}
```

The type of the parameter `item` now depends on the enum member passed as `storeName`.

```
main({
  storeName: stores.verse,
  getA(item) {
    // ^? item: { a: string; d: boolean; }
    item.a;
    item.d;
  },
});

main({
  storeName: stores.book,
  getA(item) {
    // ^? item: { a: string; b: number; }
    item.a;
    item.b;
  },
});
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAzgLgewE7BlA3gKClARghAawBpsoBjACwEMAHOYJUnAN0ZmFIF9NNyEQ8KCgAmYcoygBeDGQDa8ZKgB0+IgF0AXBijVtAInhIAliADm+4nm0BGKF2ZQFiFDGVU6DJFp16ohuBNzSwptACZ7R2clNzYkDh90XQMjUwsrEW0AM2oAGw5IzC4Abl4ssBByOGMBKAhqUwAeAGUoYAAPBhARNEVXAD4ACiwcPuAAOWoITjIzYDgAQW5tEdgXCangbWbSnDnF7UHjBghtOABPWmAELOFgMQkkOWb1AEppfqgWBGMRUq53qt+II4FBjsBoDJROJGNEUJNpupdlB9gsjidXsiUHAwEgQP9ePVTMMyGMEVs1jFlHEOI5UeiIYCyDgAPQsqAAPQA-GCTitkmsgmZilBMngCLlgNR8fZmbyIcpqMicOCIMo-mQHEVMYSGiASaN1uTtGM3GoSLN5mjVUycKz2dz5adfCbAmkRbhtOAILhGCKeHanYrlUHcMitQDSkA)

Comment: My large thanks to you, Tobias. After a bit of struggling with making generic from an arrow function and rereading your answer, everything works like a charm!